# Почему with...as считывает не весь файл, а только 1 строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Подробности:

есть файл с таким вот содержимым:

```
Петров;85;92;78
Сидоров;100;88;94
Иванов;58;72;85
```

Программа, изложенная ниже считывает только 1 строку из файла, после чего with...as на чтение перестает работать. В чем проблема?

Программа:

```
import os

p = os.path.join("Some URI")

arr = []
j = 0
average = [0] * 3
with open(p, "r") as inf:
        string = inf.readline().split(";")
        sum = 0
        for i in range(3):
            average[i] += int(string[i + 1])
        for i in range(3):
            sum += int(string[i + 1])
        arr.append(sum / 3)
        sum = 0
        j += 1


for i in range(len(average)):
    average[i] /= j

p = os.path.join("Some URI")
with open(p, "w") as onf:
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        onf.write(str(arr[i]) + "\n")
    s = ""
    onf.write(str(average[0]) + " " + str(average[1]) + " " + str(average[2]))
```

Comment: потому что `inf.readline().split(";")` - не в цикле. Т.е. вы читаете только одну строку. Но лучше посмотрите [как это можно сделать более элегантно](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples)

Comment: А разве сама конструкция with...as не дает гарантии того, что файл будет считан до конца?

Comment: `with ...` - это менеджер контекста, который не имеет ничего общего с чтением файла. Он только задаёт границу видимости переменной `inf` (в вашем случае), все остальное зависит от программиста

Comment: @Nabla, если вы читаете из файла через `readline()`, то вы читаете по одной строке за раз (это очевидно из названия метода). От того что вы читаете из конструкции `with open` это поведение никак не меняется.

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
with open(p, "r") as inf:
        string = inf.readline().split(";")
```

используйте

```
with open(p, "r") as inf:
    for line in inf:                      # добавлено (читать строку после строки)
        string = line.split(";")          # здесь разница
```